# Why does my sudoku solver work in serial but not in parallel using openMP?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, backtracking, sudoku

I am writing a code that solves a NxN soduku puzzle in parallel using openMP. The code works fine when i compile without -fopenmp option, but when I compile with -fopenmp I get weird results.
Here is a snippet of the relevant part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

const int SUBSIZE = 4;
const int SIZE = SUBSIZE*SUBSIZE;

typedef struct {
    int *grid;
    int row;
    int col;
    int filled_cells;
} State;


int last = 0;

int solvePartialBoardBFS(State *state, int **grids){
    int row = state->row;
    int col = state->col;
    int *grid = state->grid;
    int filled_cells = state->filled_cells;

    if (filled_cells == 1){
        grids[last] = grid;
        printSolution(grids[last]);
        last++;
        return 0;
    }

    // end of grid, solution found.
    if (row == SIZE) {
        return 1;
    }

    //End of row, move to next row
    if (col == SIZE) {
        state->row = row + 1;
        state->col = 0;
        return solvePartialBoardBFS(state, grids);
    }

    // Skip if non-empty cell
    if (grid[row * SIZE + col] != 0){
        state->col = col + 1;
        return solvePartialBoardBFS(state, grids);
    }

    //Try all possible values for the cell
    int solved = 0;
    for (int value = 1; value <= SIZE; value++) {
        if (!solved && validateBoard(grid, row, col, value)) {
            int *newGrid = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE * SIZE);
            memcpy(newGrid, grid, sizeof(int) * SIZE * SIZE);
            newGrid[row * SIZE + col] = value;
            State newState = {newGrid, row, col + 1, filled_cells + 1};
            int task_solved = solvePartialBoardBFS(&newState, grids);
            if (task_solved) {
                solved = 1;
                memcpy(grid, newGrid, sizeof(int) * SIZE * SIZE);
            }
            free(newGrid);
        }
    }
    return solved;
}


int solveBoardDFS(int *grid, int row, int col){
        //printf("New branch (%d)\n!", rec_count++);
        // end of grid, solution found.
        if (row == SIZE) {
                return 1;
        }

        //End of row, move to next row
        if (col == SIZE) {
                return solveBoardDFS(grid, row + 1, 0);
        }

        // Skip if non-empty cell
        if (grid[row*SIZE + col] != 0){
                return solveBoardDFS(grid, row, col+1);
        }

        //Try all possible values for the cell
        for (int value = 1; value <= SIZE; value++) {
                if (validateBoard(grid, row, col, value)) {
                        grid[row*SIZE + col] = value;
                        if (solveBoardDFS(grid, row, col + 1)) {
                                return 1;
                        }
                        // backtrack
                        grid[row*SIZE + col] = 0;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int grid[SIZE * SIZE];
    FILE *fp = fopen("sudoku.csv", "r");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    int i = 0;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        char *token = strtok(line, ",");
        while (token != NULL) {
            grid[i++] = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // Allocate memory for the array
    int **boards = (int **)malloc(200000 * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        boards[i] = (int *)malloc(SIZE*SIZE * sizeof(int));
    }
    State state = {grid, 0, 0};
    solvePartialBoardBFS(&state, boards);
    printf("PRINTING OUTSIDE FUNCTION\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++){
        printSolution(boards[i]);
    }

    int flag = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) shared(flag)
    for (i = 0; i < last; i++){
        int solution_found = solveBoardDFS(boards[i], 0, 0);
        if (solution_found && flag == 0){
                #pragma omp critical
                {
                        flag = 1;
                        printSolution(boards[i]);
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation of code:
A function not included in this snippet uses BFS to generate all possible boards for the first 10 filled cells, creating about 130k unique boards. I save each board and store them in the array of pointers "boards". I then iterate over this, effectively passing each board to the function solveBoardDFS that will solve the board completely using DFS.

When I run it without openMP, I get the expected result:

```
+
| 16  2 14  1 |  5  8  6 11 | 10 13 15  7 |  9  3  4 12 |
|  3  4 10  5 |  1  2  7 13 | 14  9 12 11 |  6 15  8 16 |
| 15  7  8 13 |  9  3 12 10 |  1  6 16  4 |  2  5 11 14 |
|  6 12 11  9 | 14  4 15 16 |  2  3  5  8 | 13  1  7 10 |
+
| 13  3  7  2 |  6 16 11 12 |  4  1  8 10 |  5  9 14 15 |
|  4  5 16  8 |  2  1  9 14 |  3 15 11 12 |  7  6 10 13 |
|  9  1  6 15 |  3  7 10  4 | 13  5  2 14 | 16 11 12  8 |
| 14 10 12 11 | 15  5 13  8 |  6 16  7  9 |  3  4  1  2 |
+
| 10  6  1  4 |  7 11  8  9 | 12  2 13 16 | 15 14  5  3 |
|  2  8  5  3 | 10 14 16 15 | 11  7  9  1 |  4 12 13  6 |
| 12 15  9  7 |  4 13  3  2 |  8 14  6  5 | 11 10 16  1 |
| 11 14 13 16 | 12  6  5  1 | 15 10  4  3 |  8  7  2  9 |
+
|  7 13 15 14 | 11 12  4  3 | 16  8 10  6 |  1  2  9  5 |
|  1 11  3 12 | 16  9  2  6 |  5  4 14 13 | 10  8 15  7 |
|  8  9  2  6 | 13 10 14  5 |  7 11  1 15 | 12 16  3  4 |
|  5 16  4 10 |  8 15  1  7 |  9 12  3  2 | 14 13  6 11 |
+
```

But when I run it with openMP I get this output:

```
+
| 1597449657  5 893616101 -904939001 |  9  8  2 11 | 16 13 10  7 | 15  3  4 14 |
|  3  4 4977  2 | 16  8 10  7 | 14  5 15  9 |  6  1 11 13 |
| 11 15  1  2 |  3  5  0  7 |  0  6 1918611648 22003 | 1918607104 22003 1918607360 22003 |
|  9  8  1 13 | 16  5  6  0 |  0 14  0  0 |  0  0  7  2 |
+
| 13  2  7  0 | 16 15 11  3 |  0  0  6 10 |  4 14  9  1 |
|  0  0  6  9 |  0 10  0  0 |  3 15  0  0 | 1918607200 22003  0  7 |
|  0  1  0  0 |  0  4  8 13 | 1918607232 22003  6 14 | 16 11 12  3 |
| 16 10 11  5 |  2  1  1  6 | 132164  8  1  4 | 1918607328 22003 15 14 |
+
| 10 14  8  4 |  1  0 18 12 |  2  0  0 16 |  0  0  5  0 |
|  0  0  5  0 |  0  3 13 10 | 14  7  9 15 |  2  4  1  6 |
|  2  3  9  7 |  4  6 14 16 | 1918607488 22003 12  5 |  8 10 15 13 |
|  1 14 16 15 |  5  0 12  0 |  0  3  4  0 |  0  0  0 11 |
+
|  7 16 15 14 | 11 12  0  0 | 1918607616 22003  0  6 |  1  2  0  0 |
|  0 11  3 12 |  0  0  0  0 |  0 16  7  1 | 10  8 14  9 |
|  4  9 13  1 |  8  7  6  5 | 1918607744 22003 14  2 | 11 16  3 12 |
|  8  6  2 10 |  1 16 14  4 |  9 12  3 11 |  5  7 13 15 |
+

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am new to C so im sure my code is very messy and i'd appreciate general tips, but im mainly focused on parallelizing the loop that runs the BFS algorithm on all the boards.

EDIT: if it helps, here is the original sudoku board that is being worked on:

```
+
|  0  2  0  0 |  0  8  0  0 |  0 13  0  7 |  0  3  4  0 |
|  3  4 10  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  9 12  0 |  0  0  8  0 |
| 15  0  0 13 |  0  0  0 10 |  0  6  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |
|  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  7  0 |
+
| 13  0  7  0 |  0  0 11  0 |  0  0  0 10 |  0  0  0  0 |
|  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0 15  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |
|  0  1  0 15 |  3  0  0  0 | 13  5  0 14 | 16 11 12  0 |
|  0 10  0  0 | 15  0  0  0 |  0 16  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |
+
| 10  0  0  4 |  0  0  0  9 | 12  2  0 16 |  0  0  5  0 |
|  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  7  9  0 |  0  0  0  6 |
|  0  0  9  7 |  4  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  5 |  0  0  0  0 |
|  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |
+
|  7  0 15 14 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  6 |  1  2  0  0 |
|  0 11  3 12 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 | 10  8  0  0 |
|  0  9  0  0 |  0  0  0  5 |  0  0  0  0 |  0  0  0  0 |
|  0  0  0 10 |  0  0  0  0 |  0 12  3  0 |  0  0  0  0 |
+
```

Comment: Where is `last` declared and initialized? Most probably, `last` is bigger than your array. In serial code, you find a solution before it can cause a problem (`i` becomes bigger than your array).

Comment: As a general rule, it's best to avoid using "magic numbers" like `200000` in your code. Instead, calculate them or use constant variables with names that describe their function.

Comment: @Laci last is declared in a global scope. It is only modified in the serial part of the code when running the BFS function, so once it reaches the parallel point, there is no more code that modifies this value. I also put a print statement in the parallel loop and confirmed that **last = 132164** for all threads, which should be smaller than the size of **boards**.

Comment: In this case, another explanation is that you run out of stack. Try increasing stack size. If it does not solve your problem please create a [mre].

Comment: @Laci I reduced the problem size such that stack size shouldn't be an issue but the problem persists. I have although isolated the problem to somewhat and I think the `solvePartialBoardBFS()` could create the problem. inside this function, in the loop that checks `if (filled_cells == 1)`, i print every grid copied to the list `boards`, and I get the correct output. Yet when I print the same list elements once I am outside the function, I get the same corrupted output as previously shown.

Comment: @Laci I added the `solvePartialBoardBFS()` in my question. I'd appreciate if you could take a look at it.

Comment: In this line (`grids[last] = grid`), you are copying a pointer of a temporary array that is freed before the `solvePartialBoardBFS()` function returns. Instead of copying the pointer, you should copy the content of the array.

Comment: I am very interested in your question. I can't help you with the use of openMP but maybe with the solving algorithm without openMP which apparently works. This type of algorithm which uses notions like BFS, DFS or even partial boards is new to me. Is there any documentation describing this algorithm, e.g. on Wikipedia?